# Deserialize JSON string into current class

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a `Load` function in my C# Model, and in that I want to be able to take a JSON string and deserialize it into the current model, for example:

```
this = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(leJson);
```

But obviously I can't do that, but I'm struggling on thinking how to do it.

Comment: there can be possibility that your model and Json is different show your class and json sample data

Comment: Well, the error is in the compiler, not at runtime. The error if i try and set a value to `this` is `Cannot assign to '<this>' because it is read-only`.

Comment: why are you using `this` , assign it to class reference variable

Comment: How would I do that from inside the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's impossible. You cannot write to the `this` variable from within the instance. You should do that from an outside class. Or have your method return the class instance:

```
public static Settings GetSettings()
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(leJson);
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to load, and apply, settings inside the class?

Comment: No, not globally. You will have to do it property by property if you want to do this from inside the class. The easiest would be to simply get a new instance if you have lots of properties.

Comment: Ah okay, that's annoying but on well.

Comment: @AgentFire, what about them?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov `DeserializeObjectAsync` returns `Task`, so yuo might want to await for it. Otherwise, `Task<Settings>` does not simply casts to `Settings`.

Comment: @AgentFire, yes, good point, I haven't noticed that. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov okay, I let you do that :P